# text/html output when requesting JSONP

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have been playing around with the jQuery library the last week or two.

Very handy! I am now playing with the AJAX requests to retrieve things such as the weather, current downloads and more, which have been going well so far!

I have now tried to connect up to my ISP to get my current data usage (peak, off peak etc).

When I use Chrome, I can manually type the variables into the URL and have the required JSON code show in the browser. The issue is, that it seems to return `text/html` instead of `application/json`.

When you go into developer tools, it shows `text/html`. This make it difficult for me to retrieve the data from my home server using AJAX and `JSONP`. See here for a failed query (but you can still see the `text/html` output, which is in a JSON format! 
[Failed JSON Query on ISP](https://toolbox.iinet.net.au/cgi-bin/api.cgi)

My question is, how could I get this data from the server URL, then make it into JSON that jQuery can read?

When I try the `.load` , `$.get` functions I run into Cross Origin Issues...

EDIT:[Here is the PDF documentation for the API (Download at the bottom of the page)](https://code.google.com/p/iinet-api/issues/detail?id=16&can=1) 
Notice that I need to append certain values (user / pass / token). My ultimate aim is to have my JS  read these values and store them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The issue is, that it seems to return `text/html` instead of `application/json`.

That's a serverside issue. Go and file a bug report.

> This make it difficult for me to retrieve the data

Not by itself. You should be able to override the settings how responses are parsed, e.g. in [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) by using the `datatype` parameter.

> using AJAX and JSONP

Notice that you cannot use [JSONP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP), as it is not supported by that API (judging from the docs and a simple `?callback=test` try). If you want support for that, file a bug report against the service provider.

> When I try the `.load`, `$.get` functions I run into Cross Origin Issues...

Yes. They don't send [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) headers either. I suspect that this API is only used internally, and by devices that are not subject to a same-origin policy.

> how could I get this data from the server URL, then make it into JSON that jQuery can read?

Use a [proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server) on your own server (that runs in the same domain as your app). It can also fix that `content-type` header.

For more details see also [Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3076414/1048572), though most of the methods require cooperation of the service provider (to implement serverside features).

Comment: Ok - Its good to know that I am not doing (much) wrong. It is the server that is causing the issues for not supporting the JSONP callback. I have lodged a support request with them. To get around this, I would need to make a proxy / php page which gets the data, then inject that via my script, correct?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "inject", but yes, you would need to ajax-call your own API that then gets the data.

Comment: Great. Using a PHP file (taken from elsewhere) in combination with `$.parseJSON()` has yielded me a result! It's a shame you need to go to the extra effort of the PHP page, but hey, its something else for me to learn!

Answer (score 1):

If i understand you correctly You ask for a certain value and it gives you a string. For most API's in the world they send a string that you have to parse into JSON or some language code. I would suggest looking at [Parsing JSON Strings](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/) link. It explains how to take well formated strings and parse them into JSON readable objects.

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( '{ "name": "John" }' );
alert( obj.name === "John" );
```

if you go on further and start using php take a look that [Parsing JSON Strings with PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

**EDIT:**

use .done() method to grab text from other pages after AJAX call.

```
$.ajax(...).done(function(html){
    //do what you want with the html from the other page
    var object = $.parseJSON(html)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. How would I be able to get the information to parse? The info I need to parse is on another domain (in the body, see the FAILED query link above). JSONP fails as I believe that its looking for `application/json` but receiving `text/html`

Comment: This is the error I get in the console which then stops the rest of the code running `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : api.cgi?_USERNAME=(OMITTED)&_PASSWORD=(OMITTED)&callback=jQuery21108770702176261693_141885948911…:1`

Comment: `$.ajax(...).done(function (html){ var obj = $.parseJSON(html)})`

Comment: Would it be because the server seems to not accept JSONP that the above code will not run? The callback seems to fail (it has a colon in the callback) which causes it to fail.